# Exceptions in C++ how to get back to "main menu"

Tags: c++, exception

Well, I'm studying for an exam so I tried to keep my code as simple as possible, but then something very weird happened: the exercise was to change the following code and, by using exceptions, get back to the main menu.

Here's the code of the question:

```
void ha_ha_loop()
{
 int i, c;

 while(1)
  {
     for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
     {
       cout << "Ha Ha Ha" << endl;
       sleep(3);
     } // for 
    ask_return(); 
  } // while 

} // ha_ha_loop 

void dollar_loop()
{

 int i;

   while(1)
    {
     for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
      {
        cout << "$$$$$$$$$ " << endl;
        sleep(3);
      } // for 

      ask_return(); 
    } /* while */

} // dollar_loop 

void mainloop()
{
  string answer;

 while (1)
 {

    cout << "Press 1 for Ha Ha Ha." << endl;
    cout <<  "Press 2 for $$$$$$$$." << endl;
    cout << "Press 3 for to quit." << endl;

    cin >> answer;

    switch (answer[0])
    {
      case '1':
       ha_ha_loop();
      case '2':
       dollar_loop();
      case '3':
       return;
    } // switch 

  } // while 

} // mainloop
```

And what I did was:

```
void ask_return() {
    char c;
    cout << "Return to main menu? y/n:"<<endl;
    cin >> c;
    if (c=='y') throw 1;
}

void ha_ha_loop()
{
 int i, c;

 while(1)
  {
     for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
     {
       cout << "Ha Ha Ha" << endl;

     } // for 
    ask_return(); 
  } // while 

} // ha_ha_loop 

void dollar_loop()
{

 int i;

   while(1)
    {
     for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
      {
        cout << "$$$$$$$$$ " << endl;
      } // for 

      ask_return(); 
    } /* while */

} // dollar_loop 

void mainloop()
{
  char answer;

 while (1)
 {

    cout << "Press 1 for Ha Ha Ha." << endl;
    cout <<  "Press 2 for $$$$$$$$." << endl;
    cout << "Press 3 for to quit." << endl;

    cin >> answer;

    switch (answer)
    {
      case '1':
       ha_ha_loop();
      case '2':
       dollar_loop();
      case '3':
       return;
    }
  }

}



int main() {
    try {
        mainloop();
    } catch (...) {
        mainloop();
    }
}
```

It works fine at the beginning, but then after one time it terminates my program with an unhandled exception message. Why?

What is the simplest correct way to do that?

Edit:
 this is a working way :

```
void ask_return() {
    char c;
    cout << "Return to main menu? y/n:"<<endl;
    cin >> c;
    if (c=='y') throw 1;
}

void ha_ha_loop()
{
 int i, c;

 while(1)
  {
     for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
     {
       cout << "Ha Ha Ha" << endl;

     } // for 
    ask_return(); 
  } // while 

} // ha_ha_loop 

void dollar_loop()
{

 int i;

   while(1)
    {
     for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
      {
        cout << "$$$$$$$$$ " << endl;
      } // for 

      ask_return(); 
    } /* while */

} // dollar_loop 

void mainloop()
{
  char answer;

 while (1)
 {
    try {
    cout << "Press 1 for Ha Ha Ha." << endl;
    cout <<  "Press 2 for $$$$$$$$." << endl;
    cout << "Press 3 for to quit." << endl;

    cin >> answer;

    switch (answer)
    {
      case '1':
       ha_ha_loop();
      case '2':
       dollar_loop();
      case '3':
       return;
    }
    } catch (...) {
    }
  }

}



int main() {
    mainloop();
}
```

Comment: Simplest way: ***Don't use exceptions for control flow.***

Comment: yeah but that was what the exercise about

Comment: Sometimes exceptions are good for control flow, eg. escaping deep recurse call.

Comment: @j_kubik: Exceptions are for *exceptional* situations.  Stuff you don't expect to happen, but want to provide some ability to handle.  Exiting a recursive function is not an exceptional case -- it's normal, and in fact required of a self-respecting program in just about any language.  If you have to use them for flow control, you're doing something wrong -- there are less intrusive ways of handling it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll only answer the "how come" part, since the simplest correct way is what you're supposed to solve yourself. When you do

```
try {
    mainloop();
} catch (...) {
    mainloop();
}
```

you execute `mainloop`, catching any exceptions. When an exception is caught, the handler executes `mainloop` again, **outside of a `try` block**. You'll want to repeatedly go into `mainloop`, catching the exception every time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's my suggestion.

First, `ask_return()` needs to get written. This is simple enough, and as far as I can tell you had it more-or-less right. I'm going to suggest actually using a `std::exception` though:

```
void ask_return()
{
    char c;
    cout << "Return to main menu? y/n" << endl;
    cin >> c;
    if ( c == 'y' )
    {
        throw std::exception(); // might as well use the class designed for this
    }
}
```

There are numerous places where you could catch the exception, but the easiest place is within `mainloop()`:

```
void mainloop()
{
    string answer;

    while (1)
    {

        cout << "Press 1 for Ha Ha Ha." << endl;
        cout <<  "Press 2 for $$$$$$$$." << endl;
        cout << "Press 3 for to quit." << endl;

        cin >> answer;

        try
        {
            switch (answer[0])
            {
                case '1':
                    ha_ha_loop();
                case '2':
                    dollar_loop();
                case '3':
                    return;
            } // switch 
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            // do nothing, let the loop re-run.
        }

    } // while 

} // mainloop
```

In this case, you don't even need to do anything about the exception: you just let the function keep looping, and it will work.

Comment: Sorry, but `std::exception` was not designed to be used for control flow. Also, don't do homework / excercises for others.

Comment: @xeo you already stated that it is not for control flow, but the question was not how to do it properly (add a flag or something to the loop) but how to catch the exception properly. It is a contrived example, would you be happer if the homework would have been, you callculate something in a loop and have a division by your calculated value, how do you handle either returning the calculated value or an error if you value becomes actually zero (divison by zero exception). Sometimes the examples might be bad, but still this is what was asked for.

Comment: And while `std::exception` was not designed for control flow, it is the exception base class to be used and certainly is better than using int as exception class, since you have a error message with your exception, but I guess thats bad too? Nobody argues with you taht using exceptions for control flow is usualy bad **in c++**

Comment: @ted Not just in C++: exceptions are used for _error management_, not for _control flow_, **no matter which language you use**. I repeat: exceptions are not "the OO way to do `goto`s".

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: While i agree, both with your statement (+1 btw) and with the idea that it should be drilled in on a regular basis, it's arguably easier (when you're first learning how exceptions work) to work with them in an environment where you know they'll always be thrown.  That pretty much *means* using them for flow control at first, with the knowledge that "this is just a learning exercise, to show how they work -- you should never do this in real life".

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: take a look at **python**, that is a language where exceptions are the way to go. Iterators use them for example and those are not exactly uncommon or bad...

Comment: @ted Well, color me intrigued.

Comment: Also, my understanding was that this was not for homework per se, so much as an old exercise (whether it be an old homework assignment or a previous test). I believe he's simply trying to understand what he did wrong before the next test. Just for whatever it's worth.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: I fully understand the objection. I would add that using python as an argument is mean, they also have pardigmeans like [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html) which I find difficult, and the exception path they choose, well its build arround different assumptions. Asa site note one reason against exceptions is that they cause stackunwinding and are expensive(slow), the second in c++ they are considered to handle exceptional events, not hte usual expected control flow. The control flow becomes unclear(cross several scope boundaries). Etienne can you give further reasons?

Comment: @ted Exceptions are not _that_ slow. And, anyway, exceptions are supposed to be _exceptional_ (and not just in C++, but also in Java or .NET, which are otherwise quite exception happy).